# Find out when an image was uploaded to a server?

Tags: image

I'm looking for a way to find out on what date an image was uploaded to a server. This image, for example:

http://tox2.tales-ch.jp/image/character/ivar/pic_ivar_b.jpg

How do I find out when it was uploaded? If I had FTP access, I can see that through the "last Modified" column. But I don't. Any ideas? :]

Comment: pull down the file and check the http headers. it MAY contain a last-modified timestamp. but that'll be about the only way you could do this, unless you've got access to the server's filesystem

Comment: How do I "pull down the file and check the http headers?" :]

Comment: simple method: firebug or httpfox add-on for firefox, hit the url, use either plugin to examine the headers. if you want to do it programatically, that's a different beast... depends on your environment and language of choice.